# running python code returning false method value

Tags: python

```
#checkapi.py
import time

def add(a,b):
    return a + b
def loop():
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        print("loop running")
loop()
```

```
#apicheck.py
import checkapi

print(checkapi.add(5, 6))
```

```
output
------
apicheck.py showing "loop running"
```

please check out this. Why this happening.

Q. How to call a running method and get it's return value ?.

Comment: You can't "call a running method". Calling a method by definition runs it. What are you trying to actually accomplish here? What do you want to do?

Comment: I don't understand the question. When you `import checkapi`, the `loop` function starts running, because it says `loop()` at the end of that file. Because that function has an infinite loop, nothing else can happen afterward. It's not at all clear what you want to happen instead.

Comment: You should guard against the file being run as a script vs loaded as a module. Do `if __name__ == "__main__": loop()` to guard against this.

Answer (score 1):

Modify `checkapi.py` in following way:

```
#checkapi.py
import time

def add(a,b):
    return a + b
def loop():
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        print("loop running")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop()
```

this will solve your issue. `if __name__ == '__main__'` says Python to run `loop()` function only if you execute script itself like `python checkapi.py`, but if you import it from other module through `import checkapi` then `loop()` is not executed and you can use this module without trouble.